# Error Viewing rdl Report on deployment machine. The definition of the report '' is invalid

Tags: reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I have some rdl reports that work fine with **Report Builder 2**. However, when I deploy my wpf application (and reports with it) on windows 8 machine, I get Report Definition Error. The Error Message says **The definition of the report '' is invalid.** The reports work fine even on my development machine under VS 2010. The reports are running under Processing Mode **Local**. Here are a few things that I tried to resolve this issue.

- Checked that the ReportViewer dll's are in the bin directory of the deployment machine
- Checked that the Report Definition is correct by running them successfully in Report Builder 2 and SQLServer 2008R2.

There is a doubt that I am not sure of. The windows 8 deployment machine has a program entry "**Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 SP1**" in the control panel. Can this be an issue. I think that, since I copied the ReportViewer dll in the bin(executable) directory of the deployed machine, these dll should be loaded and not the GAC. At this stage I am out of ideas as to why I an unable to generate reports on the deployed machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had not copied the "**Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll** into the bin directory thinking that it is not required for the winforms version of report viewer. In my developement machine this file was in the GAC and hence I did not get any errors for the same. This made me think that the dll is not required. But it is required and so had to copy this into the executable directory of my wpf application.

Nirvan.